# Change default number of columns - DataObject

Tags: oracle12c, oracle-bam

Does anybody know how can I change the default number of columns in a Simple Data Object on Oracle BAM?

[image]

I've achieved the maximum number of columns and now I need to add more columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, I used my Oracle Support account and Oracle said:

[Oracle Community - Change default number columns](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4109751)